# Website not up after Dokku deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, digital-ocean, dokku

I have created a Dokku droplet on Digital Ocean and deployed my Rails app following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-dokku-one-click-digitalocean-image-to-run-a-ruby-on-rails-app). Everything seems to be OK. no errors or whatsoever. At the end Dokku returns the URL of my app:

```
=====> Application deployed:
       http://1.1.1.1:49154
```

Of course the IP address is different :-)
But when I visit this URL it doesn't show anything, that site doesn't seem to exist.
Any idea how this might happen?
I have no domain name, I want to use the IP address because it is just a little personal app.

Answer (score 0):

i'm facing the same problem, but on amazon EC2 services.
probably in your case its the in-port configuration.

#### most of the hosting services have some setups like only allow ports 22(ssh),80(http),and sometimes 443 (for https).

please check and let me know.

to check ports, read this or something similar:
[faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/what-process-has-open-linux-port/)